# Python, sorted function: sort dictionary by value returns unexpected list

Tags: python

I am learning python sorted function, I have a sample_dictionary, I try to sort by its value. The example is as follows: name: age pair

```
sample_dict = {'andi': 65, 'george': 34, 'elvis': 44, 'david': 25, 'caleb': 18, 'broady': 27}
# Let's sort a dictionary by value
print("Key-based sort: ", sorted(sample_dict, key=lambda sample_dict: sample_dict[1]))
```

The expected out is as follows since caleb's age is only 18, why andi's age is eldest 65:

```
['caleb', 'david','broady','george','elvis','andi']
```

but when I run in python 3, it gives as following result:

```
['david', 'caleb', 'george', 'elvis', 'andi', 'broady']
```

david age is `25`, caleb is `18`. andi is eldest....

Why Why Why? My understanding is wrong that sample_dict[1] does not mean age?

Comment: You are sorting by the second letter of the name!

Comment: Then How to sort by its value, say age in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
key=lambda sample_dict: sample_dict[1]
```

Within the lambda, `sample_dict` is not a name for the original dict, but instead (because you re-used the name for the parameter) a name for each of the dict keys that is being sorted in the output. These keys are strings, so they are being sorted according to the result of using `[1]` to index into those strings.

So `'david'` and `'caleb'` are first because `'david'[1]` and `'caleb'[1]` are both `'a'`, and so on.

What you wanted is to use the `lambda`'s parameter to index into `sample_dict`, so it needs a separate name. Thus, for example: `key=lambda name: sample_dict[name]`.

Alternately, the `[1]` suggests that you wanted to sort the *items* of the dict (key-value pairs). You need to ask for those explicitly: `sorted(sample_dict.items(), key=...`. Then we can fill in our key - now `[1]` is the desired index. We should still use a different name for the `lambda` parameter, though, to avoid confusion.

Comment: I don't think the issue is with names. Even if it is named something else, the issue will still prevail since the sorting is not being done on `sample_dict.items()`

Comment: I covered that. OP showed expected output that only includes keys, after all. If we sort by using dict lookup for our sort key, it will work. (Ugh, it's hard to talk about this clearly because `key` means two different things!)

Comment: Right. Thats another way to do it. That had not actually crossed my mind!

Answer (score 1):

It will be `sorted(sample_dict.items(), key = lambda x: x[1])`

When you call `sample_dict.items()`, it returns a list of tuples, which the sorted method then iterates over and uses the lambda to sort.

If you don't call it on `sample_dict.items()`, then the `x` in the lambda gets the key values. And you it sorts on the 2nd character of the name.

Another way to do it as @Karl pointed out can be:
`sorted(sample_dict, key = lambda x: sample_dict[x])`

Answer (score 1):

When you do sample_dict[1], you go to the second letter of the key(name). It is a key:value pair not a list. You can use this code

```
x = {1: 2, 3: 4, 4: 3, 2: 1, 0: 0}
{k: v for k, v in sorted(x.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
print("Key-based sort: ", sorted(sample_dict, key=lambda sample_dict: sample_dict[1]))
```

To

```
print("Key-based sort: ", sorted(sample_dict, key=lambda s: sample_dict[s]))
```

The reason your code didn't work is because `sorted` will take in an array, and sort each element. 
You know that if you iterate through a diction like:

```
for k in dct:
    ...
```

the program will iterate through the keys, which are strings, nothing else. So, the key you are looking for for the `sorted()` will be `dict[key]`.

Answer (score 1):

Below will correctly spit out the result you were looking for!
The 'x' in the lambda function refers to the key of the dictionary.

```
print("Key-based sort: ", sorted(sample_dict, key=lambda x: sample_dict[x]))
```